# create Line Chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts

how to create this chart with python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ji81.png)

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
y2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
y3 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

plt.plot(x, y2, label='Line 1')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='Line 2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't look like this chart. I want to make a chart like this one